# Ubuntu 22.04 blank screen on VMFusion

Tags: 22.04

While running Ubuntu as a virtual machine using VMFusion, it sometimes happens that when I go to Ubuntu (VMFusion) the screen is blank.  Why is this happening?  Note: I have to forcibly shutdown Ubuntu using the VMFusion tools, which indeed is not cool.

The problem is intermittent.  Months can go by with no occurrence, but then suddenly I will get a spate of them.